# ASP.NET MVC Ajax.ActionLink's weird behavior

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing the simplest ajax request possible:

```
public ActionResult SayHello()
    {
        return Content("YYAAAY");
    }

//////////

<div id="Div1">
    <%= Ajax.ActionLink("SAY HELLO", "SayHello", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Div1" })%>
    </div>
```

It works when I start an empty ASP.NET MVC project, but when I use it in my current project, it displays the whole page recursively instead of YYAAAY phrase only.

Where might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have an unrelated javascript error that is causing it to use the default action (link) instead of retrieving the content via AJAX.  Use Firefox/Firebug and examine the console or turn on script debugging in IE and see.

Comment: I just checked it with FireBug. When I click on it, it makes a POST request and gets the whole page in the response field. No errors noticed...

Comment: I don't usually use Ajax.ActionLink -- can you show us the generated HTML?  Also, have you checked to see if there is a javascript error that occurs earlier, say when the page originally loads, that might prevent a handler from being applied?